# How to invalidate cache with React query v3?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have read react-query documentation regarding query invalidation. However, it doesn't seem to work for me. Here is the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ax from "axios";
import { useQueryClient, useQuery } from "react-query";

export default function App() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [poke, setPoke] = React.useState("pikachu");
  
  const getPokemon = async (id) => {
    try {
      const pokemon = await ax.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + id);
      return pokemon;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error();
    }
  };

  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(
    ["get-pokemon", poke],
    () => getPokemon(poke),
    { cacheTime: 100000000 }
  );

  const getGengar = () => {
    ax.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/gengar").then((res) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("get-pokemon");
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && "loading"}
      {isError && "error"}
      {data && data.data.id}
      <button onClick={() => setPoke("pikachu")}>search pikachu</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPoke("ditto")}>search ditto</button>
      <button onClick={() => getGengar()}>search gengar</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

So the function `getGengar()` should invalidate the query "get-pokemon". I should see a loading state when pressing the "get pikachu" button again. But it behaves like the cache is still valid. How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From react-query docs - [query invalidation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation).

> When a query is invalidated with `invalidateQueries`, two things happen:
>
> - It is marked as *stale*.
> - If the query is currently being rendered via `useQuery` or related hooks, it will also be refetched in the background.

Also in [important defaults](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/important-defaults) section:

- Stale queries **are refetched automatically in the background** when
  there are new activities (query instance mounted, window refocused, network reconnected...)

---

To recap, when you call `invalidateQueries()`, it makes all matching queries *stale* and stale queries when interacted are fetched again in the background. If you want to show loading state, there are 2 states you can refer to depending on the scenario:

- `isLoading`: returns `true` when fetching for the first time or after query cache is garbage collected (no cache).
- `isFetching`: returns `true` when refetching in the background. Happens when there is stale cache to display as a placeholder.

```js
const {
  isFetching, // returns true when in the fetching process
  isLoading, // returns true when in the fetching process AND no cache
  ...props,
} = useQuery(
  ["id", idQuery],
  fetchSomething
);
```

Comment: Ok cool, so the query was actually invalidated, but I could't see it, because React kept displaying the outdated data while react-query was fetching it again in the background. Is there a way to prevent the refetching? For exemple: I fetch an user's data and store them in a global state. Later, I update the name of the user, the api call succeeds, I update the global state with the new user, and invalidate the query "get-user". But here, React-query will fetch the user again, while I already have his infos.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 the intended workflow in `react-query` is that you update the new user via a `POST` or `PUT` request using `react-query` mutation hook and call invalidate cache when successful. Any active stale queries are fetched and updated again by `react-query`. Also `react-query` stores the async related data for you internally, which removes the need to store them in global state. See [this](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/does-this-replace-client-state#_top).

Comment: > For exemple: I fetch an user's data and store them in a global state


there is no need to do that. react-query is a global state manager. please just call `useQuery` whenever you need the data, and react-query will handle the rest. To avoid background refetch, set an appropriate `staleTime`. This time will tell react-query how long the data can be considered fresh, and no background refetch will happen in that time.